# Network Domain changed to wrong

Tags: networking, network-adapter, domain, workgroup

I have laptop from my company where I'm working. Unfortunelty I changed the domain (IT Network) and restart the computer (options "join a domain or workgroup")

Now I'm not able to login (message it's that is wrong password).

Can I samehow set up previous domain? 
It was like: copmuter is part of company and I'm using it......
First option into ID Network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the credentials of a *local* account to log back in your machine and the credentials of a domain account which has the right to join clients to your domain to change the settings back.

Comment: ok, so probably only administrator can do it?

Comment: No. But you need the credentials of a local account to log back in and a domain account which has the right to join computers to your domain. Since I don't know how your domain or your clients are configured, I can't answer this exactly but it is very likely that there are no more local accounts on your machine left except a local admin account.

Comment: @duenni you actually need the credentials of a domain admin to join a domain. You only need local admin credentials to change to a workgroup.

Comment: You're right. Edited the answer.